# tree.view.selection ... get text of the selected range?

Tags: javascript, html, xul

I am using this function to get the selected items in a tree

```
function getSelectedRange_autofill()
{
var tree = document.getElementById("Tree_links");
var start = new Object();
var end = new Object();
var numRanges = tree.view.selection.getRangeCount();
var dimo;
for (var t = 0; t < numRanges; t++){
    tree.view.selection.getRangeAt(t,start,end);

    for (var v = start.value; v <= end.value; v++){
    dimo = tree.view.getItemAtIndex(v);
    alert("Item " + v + " is selected. _ " + dimo);
    }
}
```

But in the alert i get on the index of the selected, and the variable dimo returns a XULElement.

How can i get the text selected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried tree.view.getCellText(col,row)? Please look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tree

Comment: Yes i know about getCellText, i just didnt know what to pass it as parameters, but i kinda se it now, thank youuuuu for your help

Comment: Well it is the opposite, i mean in getCellText we pass row first then col. `tree.view.getCellText(row,col)`